# c# save 2 textboxs to listbox and work with each information

Tags: c#, textbox, listbox, valuestack

Hello i'm working on my school project "roulette", but i got stuck and dont know how to continue, atm its working for just one bet.

I made bet system by two textbox, where you can type number and price of bet, and after click on button it goes to labels.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text) <=36) // Bet number 
            {
                label4.Text = textBox1.Text; // Bet number from textbox will be trensfered to label, to see what was your bet
                MessageBox.Show("Bet is complete");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Bet number must be from 0 to 36. Bet again");
            }

            if (Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text) <= Int32.Parse(CreditNr.Text))
            {
                BetNumber = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                BetNr.Text = BetNumber.ToString();
                CreditNumber = (CreditNumber - BetNumber);
                CreditNr.Text = CreditNumber.ToString();
                label5.Text = textBox2.Text; // Bet will be transfered to label, to see what was your bet
                MessageBox.Show("Bet is complete");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You dont have enought money");
            }
```

But it works only for one bet, is there any opinion how to make more bets, for example with listbox or etc? I need to save two values one will be, number and second is Value of bet.
For example. I wanna play and will choice numbers 1 and bet 20€, 2 and bet 15€, and 3 and bet 30€. Now i need to save this information somwhere where i can work with them, For example 1 win so 20€ will be *36.

Do you have any ideas how to realize that? I thinked about two listbox one will be for number and second for bet. But don't know how to connect the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `listView` instead of `listBox`

On form load add two column:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  listView1.View = View.Details;
  listView1.Columns.Add("Number", 50, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
  listView1.Columns.Add("Bet", 50, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
}
```

And when you creating a new bet just get the values and save to the listView

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
item.Text = number;
item.SubItems.Add(bet.ToString());
listView1.Items.Add(item);
```